# How to do calculations with aggregated results of a row

Tags: views, 10

I'm using Views Aggregator Plus do aggregate the results of columns. However, I cannot do calculations with the result. This is because the module always does the aggregation last.

The aggregation groups several individual items that are the same and sums the numbers to a total.
This then looks like this:

| ITEM | DEBIT | CREDIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 213 | 213 |
| Item B | 157 | 722 |
| Item C | 489 | 100 |

What I want to achieve is that when both debit and credit have a result, they need to be substracted from each other *(if debit is larger than credit: debit minus credit, if credit is larger: credit minus debit, if equal: 0)*.

Giving this:

| ITEM | DEBIT | CREDIT | DEBIT RESULT | CREDIT RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 213 | 213 | 0 | 0 |
| Item B | 157 | 722 | 0 | 565 |
| Item C | 489 | 100 | 389 | 0 |

What solution would be best to tackle this problem?
Can I achieve this with twig in views or templating? Or is the only solution to make a module?